# Creating 3 new python files using sed in Bash script

Tags: python, sed

I need to replace a single value dt=DELTAT in a python file with 3 different numbers. For each number I want to create a new file lets call them file1.py,file2.py and file3.py here is my attempt. the variable dt only appears once in the python file so this should be easy but I can't quite seem to get it. the original file is lorenz_x.py

```sh
    for k in {1..3};do
    for i in 0.0001 0.0005 0.001;
    do
      sed -i -e "s/DELTAT/i/g" "$lorenz_x.py" > lorenzk_x.py/?k[]=i
    done
    done
```

Thanks for the help!

I was expecting to have 3 new files like I names above but instead I got
lorenz.txt: line 4: lorenzk_x.py/?k[]=i: No such file or directory.

I used vi lorenz.txt to create the file and bash lorenz.txt to run it. note the .txt is irrelevant here in linux and my new file names will have extension .py

Comment: Wouldn't it be hugely easier to pass the DELTAT value as a command line parameter?

Comment: Your nested loops would result in **9** loops, which is not what you want.  You would have needed `"s/DELTAT/$i/"` to pass the value, and you don't want a `"$"` in front of `lorenz_x.py`.  Finally, the output file would simply be `lorenz${k}_x.py`, except for the other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in 0.0001 0.0005 0.001; do
   ((k++))
   sed -e "s/DELTAT/$i/g" lorenz_x.py > "lorenz${k}_x.py"
done
```

Save the code avobe as `lorenz.sh` (or whatever name), and run with `bash lorenz.sh`. Then three files lorenz1_x.py, lorenz2_x.py and lorenz3_x.py will be generated with corresponding number substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is a much better plan than the hokery you're attempting.

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print( "You must pass DELTAT as a float argument." )
    sys.exit(-1)

DELTAT = float(sys.argv[1])
...
...
```